# Numerical integration of product of two functions

Tags: numerical-methods

My question is in the context of spectroscopy/determination of excited state lifetimes.

I have to numerically integrate the following integral using MS Excel

$$
\int_0^{\infty} F(\lambda) \epsilon (\lambda) \lambda^4 \mathrm{d}\lambda
$$

where

$F(\lambda)$ is an emission spectra (normalized to an area of 1), $\epsilon (\lambda)$ is the molar absorption coefficient spectrum, and $\lambda$ is the wavelength.

I have one issue The integral is a product of two functions. Let's say I use the trapezoidal approximation. Then I have that

$$
I \approx \frac{b-a}{2}[f(a)+f(b)]
$$

I have no trouble implementing this for a single function, but how do I do this for a product of two functions? Can I split the procedure into several individual parts?

I hope my question is understood.

Comment: What are the values of $F(\lambda)$ and $\epsilon(\lambda)$ if they are out of the given range? Are they $0$?

Comment: I see two problems: first, to use all of your $\epsilon$ data, you need to *extrapolate* your $F$ data, which is an inherently risky procedure unless you have a good model to justify your extrapolation. Second, it's not clear what should happen for $\lambda$ outside the domain of your $\epsilon$. I can see why the part for $\lambda$ less than 350 nm might not matter (because the $\lambda^4$ creates a bias to the right), but you must have quite a bit of decay in $F$ and/or $\epsilon$ in order to be able to neglect the region where $\lambda$ is more than 800 nm.

Comment: Inside the range from 410 to 650 nm you should interpolated the data for $F$ using straight forward linear interpolation, i.e $F(411) = (F(410) + F(412))/2$. This will introduce an error which is $O(h^2)$, where $h=1 nm$ is your current step size. But the trapezoidal rule is already $O(h^2)$ accurate, so you can live with that. As addy2012 and Ian have already remarked we need more information about the behavior of the data outside the range from 410 to 650 nm.

Comment: The functions with the larger range goes toward a limit of zero, so I decide to just delete the data points outside of the other function. It would of course be better to have the extra data for the $\epsilon$ function, but I don't. So problem 1 is "fixed". Perhaps the second challenge I mentioned has a trivial solution that I don't see (I am not used to numerical integration, I am a chemist!).

Comment: @AndersMB there is no problem with multiplying the values of $F$ and $\epsilon$ while summing up the integral.

Comment: So I multiply the values for $F$ and $\epsilon$ (and $\lambda^4$) at each data point, and then sum? That was a simple solution!

Comment: Do you need an error estimate as well?

Comment: just define $f(a)=F(a)\epsilon(a)$ and use the approximation for this function

Comment: Thank you. How does the factor $\lambda^4$ enter into the approximation?

Comment: @AndersMB The same way, you can use $f(x)=F(x)\epsilon(x)x^4$ instead. So at least for integration on [410,650] everything is OK. But you should be careful about error bounds outside this region.

Comment: The particular approximation becomes: $\frac{\lambda_{i+1}-\lambda_i}{2} \cdot [F(\lambda_i) \epsilon (\lambda_i) \lambda_i^4 + F(\lambda_{i+1}) \epsilon (\lambda_{i+1}) \lambda_{i+1}^4]$? I am confused about the indices for the $\lambda^4$ factor.

Comment: @AndersMB With the trapezoidal rule that's right.